# Construct an algorithm which checks whether it is true that  [] =  (, ) for all  ∈ .

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a digraph $ = (, )$ with integer weights on the edges, vertex $ ∈ $, and an array $$ of $||$ size. Also, $[] \geqslant  (, )$ (shortest path between  and  in given graph) holds for all $ ∈ $.
The digraph is represented by adjacency lists with weights. Construct an algorithm which checks whether it is true that $ [] =  (, )$ for all $ ∈ $.
Algorithm running time must be linear, that is, $ (|| + ||)$.

First of all, I thought of BFS, but here we have a weighted graph. Then there was an idea to use the shortest paths algorithm for DAGs, but there is no way I can prove that given graph is acyclic. Bellman-Ford algorithm can calculate an array of shortest paths, but it performs for  $ (||)$. To be honest, I really don't know how without calculating shortest distancies solve this problem in linear time.

Comment: BFS will do, what is the problem with it being weighted?

Comment: @Phicar BFS in an instance such as this has an extra $\log |G|$ factor in the running time though. As this is a *decision* problem I don't think running BFS on $G$ from $s$ is the answer here.

Comment: @Mike, thanks but from where are you getting this log factor?

Comment: @phicar The log factor comes when the edges have lengths taking on other values besides those in $\{1, \infty\}$. The BFS algorithm, for these general instances, maintain a queu and pick from the queu the vertex $v$ still in the queu **with the smallest value of** $\delta(v,s)$, which requires the queu being in sorted order. For the simpler cases where the edges all have length 1 or $\infty$ however, it suffices to calculate $N(s)$, then $N^2(S)$, and so on and so forth, and then $\delta(v,s)$ is the smallest integer $\ell$ s.t. $v \in N^{\ell}(s)$.

Comment: @Mike, oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

> Claim: Let $a$ be an array on $V$ where $a[v] \ge \delta(V,s)$ for all $v \in V(G)$. Then $a[v] = \delta(v,s)$ iff both (a) $a[s]=0$ and (b) $a[v] \le a[w]+\ell(wv)$ for each $w \in V(G)$ and each $v$ such that $wv$ is an arc in $G$, and where $\ell(wv)$ is defined to be the length of the arc $wv$.

Can you see why this is? If not, here is another hint:

> Let $v$ be any vertex in $V(G)$, and let $P$ be any path from $s$ to $v$ in $G$, including a shortest such path. Then if $a$ satisfies (a) and (b), then $a[v] \le a[s] + \ell(P)$ $=$ $\ell(P)$, where $\ell(P)$ is defined to be the length of $P$ in $G$. So then the inequality $a[v] \le \ell(P)$ must follow for each such $v$ and each such $P$. But then we are also given $a[v] \ge \delta(v,s)$ for each such $v$. So what must one conclude?

Comment: oh, I see and now have a working solution, thanks a lot! But one more question - I just have thought of negative cycles in given graph. My current algorithm wouldn't detect it, but I suppose that even if I added some kind of check for that, it definetely wouldn't work in linear time (am I right?)

Comment: @Meta what I gave is fine as long as the digraph has no negative cycles, including negative-length cycles with 2 arcs. Of course you would need to check w your professor or textbook but I am about certain that this would be a given. I don't think there are any linear-time algorithms for finding whether or not a digraph has a negative-length cycle.